# Laravel/SendinBlue Missing to parameter

Tags: php, laravel, sendinblue

I've been working with:
https://github.com/agence-webup/laravel-sendinblue

Setup everything I need but still I got one error:

```
{"code":"missing_parameter","message":"'to' is required"}
```

I tried to insert the **To** method, but also that didn't work. I'm stuck.

My controller:

```
$log = new LogController();
Mail::to($parameters['mail'])->send(new Verification($parameters));
```

My mailable build:

```
return $this
    ->view([])
    ->subject(SendinBlueTransport::USE_TEMPLATE_SUBJECT)
    ->sendinblue(
        [
            'template_id' => 3,
            'tags' => ['information'],
            'params' => [
                'FIRSTNAME' => $this->user,
                'LASTNAME' => $this->verificationCode,
            ],
        ]
    );
```

Comment: if you do ``` dd($parameters); ``` ,what does it output?

Comment: @marwaneEzzaze $parameters is just an array that I created. It contain mail, username and verification_code. But that isn't wrong. I don't know where I need to put To method or something to give the To

Comment: you can either give it an array of emails, or a User object, take a look here : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#sending-mail

Comment: @MarwaneEzzaze and what I'm doing now? I already use the TO method, but it doesn't work.